# automatic creation of new list from values of old list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

one sharepoint list is as follows
ListA

```
colA     colB     
Tim      TimA
Tim      TimB
John     JohnA
John     JohnB
Tim      TimC
```

how can i automatically create a new list using values of ListA
ListB

```
ColAA    ColBB
Tim      3                           ( because there are 3 items for Tim in ListA) 
John     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not sound proper but the best possible way I see that is to export your lists to excel, do the calculations there and then paste/export the result columns back into a new list in sharepoint. Other than that .NET code or even DataForm XSLT customization (not even considerable due to complexity) for such simple task would be overkill.